# How to listen/download podcasts onto an older iPod?

Tags: ios, podcast

I have an older iPod touch, running iOS 6.1.6. This is its last upgrade for iOS apparently.

It can no longer connect with the latest version of iTunes, so I cannot sync with my computer. I am [unable to download the iOS Podcast app](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6067236). It does not have a version compatible before iOS 7.1.

I am looking for an app which will *run* on this iPod and can allow:

- Search for and download podcasts
- Playback podcasts
- Available and compatible with iOS 6.1.6 (or earlier). Ideally directly from AppStore